# Where should I place unmanaged .dlls in a .NET project using VS2008?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, dll, unmanaged

So far I've been placing the dll into the /bin folder because it seems to be the only place it will get loaded when a DllImport'd function is called, but it just doesn't feel right since it's the output folder and it'll probably be wiped after a 'project clean' or 'rebuild all' operation.

How should I do this? Thanks in advance.

Note: I cannot embed the .dll into the .exe because the author explicitly wants the dll to be visible from the outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

- Create a folder into your project
- Place your unmanaged assemblies in there
- Change `"Copy to Output Directory"` to `"Copy If Newer"` at Properties tab.

Comment: Okay.  But don't create a new folder, the app still won't be able to find the DLLs.  And use Copy If Newer, the app isn't going to change the DLLs.

Comment: I suggest to create that folder to separate that files; will it create same folder on output directory?

Answer (score 1):

Use VS to create a new folder in your project called Lib.  Copy your DLLs there and reference them from there.

Comment: Referencing works only for managed DLLs (or COM DLLs, but in that case the reference is actually to the tlbimp/aximp-ed managed wrapper, and the COM DLL is not copied (because it is presumed to be registered)).

Comment: Would it work if I explicitly reference the DLL path as in DllImport( "Lib/xxx.dll" ) ?